# only show future appointments PHP

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I am trying to learn PHP by myself so i decided to create a little health appointment manager.
I tried to do a filter in the Controller so it only shows the future appointments in the index view but I can not find the right way to do it:
Here´s is what I wrote down in my Controller and my view:

Controller:

```
    {
        $citas = Cita::all();
        $fecha_hora = get('fecha_hora');
        if($fecha_hora>date_default_timezone_get()){
            return view('citas/index',['citas'=>$citas]);
        }

    }
```

and my index view:

```
@include('flash::message')
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.create', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                        {!!   Form::submit('Crear cita', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.index', 'method'=>'get']) !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <br>
                            {!! Form::submit('Citas pasadas',['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-sm']) !!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.index', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                            {!! Form::submit('Todas las citas', ['class'=> 'btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right'])!!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                            <br><br>
```

What i want is to only show the future appointments in the main view but also have a tab "Citas pasadas" (Past appointments in english) where i can see only past appointments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can prepare scopes in your `Model`file. Something like this.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Cita extends Model
{
    public function scopeUpcoming($query) {
        return $query->where('start_time', '>', date('Y-m-d H:m:s'))->orderBy('start_time', 'desc');
    }

    public function scopePrevious($query) {
        return $query->where('start_time', '<', date('Y-m-d H:m:s'))->orderBy('start_time', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Then, access them like `Cita::upcoming()` or `Cita::previous()`